# Comparing strings in two different dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Im trying to compare two Dataframes that got different sets of data, although there should be some common values between them, im trying to find those.
So, lemme insert what ive done so far based on reading documentation n googling.

```
datosEJE = pd.read_excel("8e80e3c7-8c7c-4434-b5b2-e75b5f21616e.xls")
googleSheetsData = pd.read_csv("REGISTRO DE CAUSAS - NUEVOS INGRESOS Y EXPEDIENTES EN TRAMITE.csv")
googleSheetsData = googleSheetsData.dropna(thresh = 5)
#cargamos en memoria csvs y xls
listaEJE = datosEJE[["CUIJ"]]

googleSheetsList = googleSheetsData[["CUIJ"]].replace(to_replace={"CAU ", "IPP ", "DEB ", "INC ", "IP ", "PP ", "I", "NC ", "PP","P-"},value="",regex=True)
listaEJE.columns = ['CUIJ']
googleSheetsList.columns = ['CUIJ']

listaEJE.sort_index().sort_index(axis=1) == googleSheetsList.sort_index().sort_index(axis=1)
```

Now, the part where i seem to have a bit of trouble is that sort index part, where the error i get is

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
C:\Users\IFRITZ~1\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_5212/2050009497.py in <module>
      9 googleSheetsList.columns = ['CUIJ']
     10 
---> 11 listaEJE.sort_index().sort_index(axis=1) == googleSheetsList.sort_index().sort_index(axis=1)

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\ops\common.py in new_method(self, other)
     67         other = item_from_zerodim(other)
     68 
---> 69         return method(self, other)
     70 
     71     return new_method

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\arraylike.py in __eq__(self, other)
     30     @unpack_zerodim_and_defer("__eq__")
     31     def __eq__(self, other):
---> 32         return self._cmp_method(other, operator.eq)
     33 
     34     @unpack_zerodim_and_defer("__ne__")

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py in _cmp_method(self, other, op)
   6849         axis = 1  # only relevant for Series other case
   6850 
-> 6851         self, other = ops.align_method_FRAME(self, other, axis, flex=False, level=None)
   6852 
   6853         # See GH#4537 for discussion of scalar op behavior

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\ops\__init__.py in align_method_FRAME(left, right, axis, flex, level)
    286                 left, right = left.align(right, join="outer", level=level, copy=False)
    287             else:
--> 288                 raise ValueError(
    289                     "Can only compare identically-labeled DataFrame objects"
    290                 )

ValueError: Can only compare identically-labeled DataFrame objects
```

maybe im not thinking the right way and it would be helpful if someone could nudge me in the right direction.

Comment: from the look of your program, looks like you try to compare a series from each dataframe. if you just want to check a series, why did you compare the whole dataframe when you can just have to compare one series of each dataframe?

Comment: I'm not sure if that is the best way to go but I think it should work for you...did you already looked into `pd.merge` ? with `indicator=true` you get an extra column with the information you need.

Comment: @dimaskrisrianto good question, i didnt notice that. well time to think

Comment: @Rabinzel thanks for the tip, ima look into pandas' doc and check that out